# C++ how can i use the same .h and choose different .cpp when using the same .h？

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation

here's the scenario:
"baselogger.h" contains API, and I implement these APIs in two cases(case A and case B, A correspond to 1.cpp， B correspond to 2.cpp), then how to code macro to compile different cases using different cpp to implement API in "baselogger.h"?

Comment: You can't use a macro cleanly. You'll need to select either A or B's compilation unit and resulting object code at the link step.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a macro for this. You could instead compile and link with 1.cpp in case A and compile and link with 2.cpp in case B.

CMake example:

```
option (CASE_A "Descriptive description" ON)
if (CASE_A)
    target_sources(target_name PRIVATE 1.cpp)
else ()
    target_sources(target_name PRIVATE 2.cpp)
endif ()
```

Insted of option, you can have some other condition. This is often useful for porting API to different systems.

---

But a macro based solution works too:

```
// 1.cpp
#ifdef MACRO_CASE_A
// case A implementation for baselogger.h
#endif

// 2.cpp
#ifndef MACRO_CASE_A
// case B implementation for baselogger.h
#endif
```

In this approach, simply compile both sources always.

Comment: should i use different CMakelists to do this? or just one?

Comment: @Tumb1eweed Just one. I added a CMake example.